# Fastening plastic to metal

Tags: screws

I have a thin piece of plastic (1mm thick) to be attached onto a metal cabinet door, in which a screw hole will be drilled. I'm hoping to use a small screw for this (~3-4mm long). Is M3 adequate for the job? Any M3? I thought about using PC screws, but they're a bit chunky.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How big is the plastic? Is it a small 1cm x 1cm square or a 1m x 3m sheet that covers the entire cabinet? I'd probably use some kind of glue myself.

Comment: The plastic weights about 50g and is about 2cm x 2cm. I wonder if any small screw might be useful here.

Comment: If you want to use a screw, I would use a machine screw (any size), washers and a nut.  1mm of plastic is not enough for any type of screw to bite into permanently.  As @Johnny mentioned, glue or adhesive strip would be appropriate for a light load.

Comment: Have you considered rivets? Super easy to put in and not at all clunky :)

Comment: Quality, name brand double-stick tape (foam tape, if there are irregular fit issues) would be my first plan here. Screws would be along way down the list.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot screw into a sheet metal very effectively. It would be far better to use a small bolt with a nut on the back. Alternatively a rivet could be used.

Tape or adhesive is normally how placards are attached to filing cabinets.

A simple approach is to use rubber cement. Rubber cement will securely attach the plastic and comes off easily if you need to remove it.